# How to ask for gps permission every time the flutter app opens?

Tags: flutter

I want that whenever the app is opened for use it should check gps status of the device and if it is off, it should ask for the permission and if the user clicks ok, it should enable it automatically. But it asks for the permission only once when app is installed for the 1st time. How to do it in flutter, please someone explain.

Comment: The permission plugins provide such a feature https://pub.dartlang.org/flutter/packages?q=permissions. https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/permission worked best for me when I last checked a few months ago. (didn't follow development of these packages since)

Comment: Can you share your code? It's hard to get to the solution with hardly any details.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53787755/how-to-enable-location-tracking-permissions-from-app-itself/53794339#53794339 ?