# Cannot ask for location permission on flutter

Tags: android, flutter, permissions

I'm creating a test application in flutter using [google_maps_flutter](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/google_maps_flutter) and [geolocator](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/geolocator) for tracking a phone's location. The problem is that when I ask for location permission no dialog is shown.

I've already tried 2 other packages, [simple_permissions](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/simple_permissions) and [permission](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/permission), which gave me gradle errors, now I'm trying with [permission_handler](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/permission_handler), but it can't find the permission in manifest

how I try to ask for permission

```
await PermissionHandler().requestPermission([PermissionGroup.locationAlways]);
```

My android/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    package="com.example.geolocation">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>

    <application ...
</manifest>
```

my android/app/build.gradle

```
def localProperties = new Properties()
def localPropertiesFile = rootProject.file('local.properties')
if (localPropertiesFile.exists()) {
    localPropertiesFile.withReader('UTF-8') { reader ->
        localProperties.load(reader)
    }
}

def flutterRoot = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.sdk')
if (flutterRoot == null) {
    throw new GradleException("Flutter SDK not found. Define location with flutter.sdk in the local.properties file.")
}

def flutterVersionCode = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionCode')
if (flutterVersionCode == null) {
    flutterVersionCode = '1'
}

def flutterVersionName = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionName')
if (flutterVersionName == null) {
    flutterVersionName = '1.0'
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
apply from: "$flutterRoot/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/flutter.gradle"

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28

    lintOptions {
        disable 'InvalidPackage'
    }

    defaultConfig {
        // TODO: Specify your own unique Application ID (https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html).
        applicationId "com.example.geolocalization"
        minSdkVersion 23
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
        versionName flutterVersionName
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            // TODO: Add your own signing config for the release build.
            // Signing with the debug keys for now, so `flutter run --release` works.
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
        }
    }
}

flutter {
    source '../..'
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:16.1.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.1.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.1.1'
}
```

what is prompted in my console

```
D/permissions_handler(20397): No permissions found in manifest for: $permission
I/flutter (20397): decodePermissionRequestResult called with: value:[{4: 4}]
```

Comment: You might need ```<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.location.gps" />``` in your manifest...

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53787755/how-to-enable-location-tracking-permissions-from-app-itself

Comment: @Keerti Purswani No, is not a Duplicate. In your question you are using location plugin. Here the plugin is geolocator. Probably the error is the same, but also in your question there isn't checked answer. So, don't stop people from possible answers with duplicate. Thanks

Comment: In any case @GusHill have you tried to add <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.location.gps" /> in your manifest and then Flutter clean and rebuild ?

Answer (score 2):

use the following package in flutter to get location permission :[Location permission package](https://pub.dev/packages/location_permissions)

First add the package to pubspec.yaml file after (sdk:flutter) line:

location_permissions: ^2.0.5

Second: in the main.dart file add the following lines to the beginning :

```
import 'package:location_permissions/location_permissions.dart';

PermissionStatus permission = await LocationPermissions().requestPermissions();
```